# Leaving some components out of production build in Angular2?

Tags: angular, compilation

Is there some way to leave out the components/parts of code of my choice at build time for the production build in Angular2/4?

I have an app that has an admin tool that I use locally. I would like this admin tool left out of the production version of the app. I can - of course - comment the code each time I do a production build, but is there some more elegant solution? Like conditional build on certain parts of the code?

I'm looking for something like *ngIf="buildingForProduction"-type of solution of anything in this direction. Does it exist?

Comment: If you are using `angular-cli` you could use the `environment` files: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-application-environments

Comment: And then build your routes and module imports dynamically only adding all admin related stuff when environment is production

Comment: where do you reference this admin tool?

Comment: @Maximus The main application navigation bar has a link to this admin-view. The minimum thing to do would be hiding this link, but of course more secure would be not loading the component at all. I'm using Bootstrap 4 for building the main navigation.

Comment: @cyrix This looks exactly like what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer by @cyrix.

When using ang cli, there's a folder called environment which contains the files environment.prod.ts and environment.ts by default. You can add more for different builds if you want and config your app accordingly.

These files contain an object like this:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  myVariable: 'This variable is not included in production build'
};
```

When you build your app with

```
ng build --env=prod
```

Then ang cli will use the environment.prod.ts. If you build with

```
ng build
```

Then the default environment.ts is used.

By adding variables to this environment object, you can then import it within the app and read the variables. Like this you can check if you're in the production build or not:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    console.log(environment.production); // Logs false for default environment
  }
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to modify your tsconfig.json and adding in the exclude, the folders or files your want to add.

```
"exclude": [
  "**/*file.ts", 
  "**/*config.ts"
]
```

unfortunately you only can have one tsconfig.json file per project it would be nice to have multiple like dev, prod, hope to see this feature comming soon https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3645. Hope it helps.

Comment: This won't exclude files if they're imported and used inside the project. Also with angular-cli or webpack it's possible to have multiple tsconfig which depend on the environment.